# How to pop back from native ios view to flutter view?

Tags: ios, xcode, dart, flutter, storyboard

I'm adding a new view with the storyboard to my existing flutter up. Then push it. The root view is flutter view, so I can pop back whenever native ios view  is opened.

How to pop back from native ios view to my flutter view with same UINavigationController from my root view(flutter view)?

this is my code from my flutterchannelmanager swift file to separate it from appdelegate.

```
self.storyVC = UIStoryboard(name: "StripePayment", bundle: nil)
let stripeVC: StripeViewController = self.storyVC!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "stripe_payment") as! StripeViewController
self.flutterViewController.present(mynavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Have you tried this code:-  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
to pop back controller?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya yes it works, but what I want to achieve is make my flutter view as rootviewcontroller. when I open flutter view I can go back to root again. I should update my question detail, thanks :)

Comment: Hey, I am also doing same thing but controller is not presenting instead I am pushing the controller but when i use pop view controller it is not coming to the previous flutter screen from where I am showing the native view
Instead it is going to initial splash screen of flutter app. If you have any suggestion please help

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://sz-flutter.firebaseapp.com/get-started/flutter-for/ios-devs#how-do-i-navigate-between-pages):

> In iOS, to travel between view controllers, you can use a
> `UINavigationController` that manages the stack of view controllers to
> display.
>
> Flutter has a similar implementation, using a `Navigator` and
> `Routes`. A `Route` is an abstraction for a “screen” or “page” of an
> app, and a `Navigator` is a
> [widget](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#widgets)
> that manages routes. A route roughly maps to a `UIViewController`. The
> navigator works in a similar way to the iOS `UINavigationController`,
> in that it can `push()` and `pop()` routes depending on whether you
> want to navigate to, or back from, a view.

I suggest to check the examples for further details about the implementation. Also, you can check out [this blog](https://medium.com/@cosinus84/flutter-view-controller-used-in-ios-app-using-coordinator-pattern-8896339d64ba) for a better understanding of navigation between Flutter page and native iOS page using Coordinator pattern.